# I believe I am not properly calling / returning functions in my program

Tags: python-3.x, return

I can't get this to run correctly, and I have to use 3 functions with their purposes being those of which I have them set to.

```
def lw():
    l = input("Enter the length of your rectangle: ")
    w = input("Now enter the width of your rectangle:")
    return l, w

def ap():
    l,w = lw()
    area = l * w
    perimeter = 2*1 + 2*w
    return area, perimeter

def main():
    area,perimeter = ap()
    print("With a length of", l ."and a width of", w)
    print("the area of your rectangle is", area)
    print("the perimeter of your rectangle is", perimeter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `l` and `w` are both strings, not ints or floats or whatever numeric you need. you'll need to wrap the `input(..)` calls in `int()` or `float` calls.

Comment: Also, `l` and `w` are local variables in the `lw` and `ap` functions.  `main` has no access to them as the code is currently written.  Finally, I think there is a typo in the perimeter calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def lw():
    l = input("Enter the length of your rectangle: ")
    w = input("Now enter the width of your rectangle:")
    return l, w

def ap():
    l,w = lw()
    area = l * w
    perimeter = 2*1 + 2*w
    return l, w, area, perimeter

def main():
    l,w,area,perimeter = ap()
    print("With a length of", l ,"and a width of", w)
    print("the area of your rectangle is", area)
    print("the perimeter of your rectangle is", perimeter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've made two changes: passing `l` and `w` in `ap()` function and accessing them in `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo,

I can see a number of issues with your code:

1. The first `print` statement in your `main` function seems to be calling variables that don't exist within that function's scope. You'll need to return the values of `l` and `w` from `ap()` in addition to `area` and `perimeter`. There's also a slight typo in the parameters of this statement (a `.` where a `,` should be).
2. Your perimeter calculation is a bit off. It's multiplying `2` by `1` instead of `2` by `l`, rendering `l` useless.
3. The inputs your code is requesting only returns `string` values rather than numerical ones. You'll need to pass those into either an `int()` or `float()` and return the results of those functions if you want to be able to calculate anything.